# ctrl-n - should not insert text

Tags: vimrc, autocompletion

When I am using the ctrl-n functionality (autocomplete word), it just inserts the text. I do not want to do that, instead, I would want to choose a word from the dropdown list, which I may then want to insert it later. Is there any way I can stop ctrl-n from inserting text while autocompleting? Are there any other autocomplete plugins that may have this workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word completition as you describe it's just how `Ctrl-n` works.
I use the following mapping to make autocompletition:

`inoremap <expr> <Tab> getline('.')[col('.') - 2] =~ '\w' ? "<C-N>" : "<Tab>"`

which uses `<Tab>` to automatically complete the current word if there is only one match, otherwise it shows the dropdown list if the current word could match many others.

Answer (score 4):

```
set completeopt+=noinsert
```

**noinsert** - do not insert any text for a match until the user selects a match from the menu. Only works in combination with "menu" or "menuone". No effect if "longest" is present.

For more info:

```
:h completeopt
```